# High voltage input/Low voltage, low current power supply

Tags: power-supply, transformer, flyback

Most of the times, metering devices are low power devices powered from high voltages inputs. Let's say I have 600V three phase, what would be a good approach to get 5V/50mA or 12V/100mA from this system to power a control circuit? Off the top of my head I would use a flyback converter with some 1500V rated transistor. Or maybe two switch flyback? A 60 Hz transformer would be big, I think. Has anyone had this kind of experience?

Comment: rectify -> high frequency flyback

Answer (score 1):

Galvanic isolation would be a requirement from such a high input voltage, especially for something coming from a utility grid. I would not use a 'dropper', or try to design a 600V input AC-DC flyback on the first go as you propose. (Let's be honest. If you're asking here, chances are you haven't yet developed the skillset to make a safe off-the-line switcher design at this high voltage.)

Instead, I'd play it safe and use an appropriately-rated step-down transformer with a primary wired across two phases or phase-to-neutral, then use a conventional low-voltage DC design in the secondary.

Such a transformer would be quite small as the secondary windings only need to deliver, say, 1.5VA tops, and it could be pretty well-spaced primary to secondary (end-to-end coils rather than overlapping ones). A transformer vendor could deliver this to you, fully hi-pot tested and ULR compliant.

Comment: I may not be so experienced in SMPS designs, but fortunately I take the needed safety actions when dealing with this stuff. I thought of non-isolated off-the-line switcher, but doing some research I found out they don't perform very well at such high voltage because of duty cycle resolution.

Comment: For example, this approach doesn't look bad: http://www.ti.com/tool/PMP11302 . Perhaps it can be adjusted to 690V.

Answer (score 0):

Use mains equipment to source common voltage. Use a common power supply.

It's perfectly common in 480/600+ volt industrial equipment to have a small transformer, specifically for powering machine controls, that steps down to 120V or 230V (your regional household voltage).   From there you simply hardwire an ordinary COTS power supply.

This stepdown equipment is gotten out of the "parts bin" for AC mains power and industrial controls, so manufacturers like Square D, Eaton, Siemens etc. from vendors like Greybar, City Electric or Grainger.

Then the usual DC power supply from the usual suspects.

The reason to do this is maintainability.  Any onsite electrician at your customer site will recognize the components, the troubleshooting path and will know how to get replacements.

Unless of course, you want to pull an Apple and keep them captive to you :)